# jQuery Lightbox shows up when opening page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I'm a graphic design student and I'm making a portfolio website. I wanted a lightbox as a way to show my work. I finally got everything working, except for one problem.

Whenever I load my page, the lightbox also loads. I don't want this. I want the lightbox to only show when people click on thumbnails of my work.

I followed [this](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/super-simple-lightbox-with-css-and-jquery/) tutorial from Tutsplus because I am not that familiar with jQuery. The only thing I changed in the script was so the lightbox would fade in and fade out when clicking.
This is the code I'm using

```
</script><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e) {
        //prevent default action (hyperlink)
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get clicked link href
        var image_href = $(this).attr("href");
        /*
        If the lightbox window HTML already exists in document,
        change the img src to to match the href of whatever link was clicked
        If the lightbox window HTML doesn't exists, create it and insert it.
        (This will only happen the first time around)
        */
        if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) { // #lightbox exists
            //place href as img src value
            var maxheightvalue = $("#lightbox").height() -60;
    $("#lightbox img").css("max-height", maxheightvalue + "px");
            $('#lightbox').fadeIn(400);
            $('#content').html('<img src="' + image_href + '" />');
            //show lightbox window - you could use .show('fast') for a transition

        }
        else { //#lightbox does not exist - create and insert (runs 1st time only)
            //create HTML markup for lightbox window
            var lightbox =
            '<div id="lightbox" style="display:none">' +
                '<p>Click to close<\/p>' +
                '<div id="content">' + //insert clicked link's href into img src
                    '<img src="' + image_href +'" />' +
                '<\/div>' +
            '<\/div>';
            //insert lightbox HTML into page
            $('body').append(lightbox);
        }
    });
    //Click anywhere on the page to get rid of lightbox window
    $('#lightbox').live('click', function() { //must use live, as the lightbox element is inserted into the DOM
        $('#lightbox').fadeOut(300);
    });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
```

I am pretty sure it's a real mess, but so far it's worked except for that one little thing. But if someone could clean it up (if possible) I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

your can try using this example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#some").on("click", function(){
        $("#gallery").lightbox();
    });
});
```

the above is to load the lightbox for ur gallery or desired ID.

http://api.jquery.com/on/